# How to manage smart contracts

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat

I am trying to figure out how to list and manage my published smart contracts for a specific project using hardhat. I'll appreciate any help to clarify these aspects.

1. Are all versions published or just the latest, replacing the old ones?
2. Is there any way to list and manage them?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by managing? Please elaborate your question.